# Sum positive even numbers

Tags: python

> Write a function that sums the positive even numbers in a list of
>   integer values. The function should be called sum_positive_even and
>   should accept a single list as a parameter. Your function should
>   return an integer value. If there are no positive even integer values
>   in the list, then your function should return 0. 
>   For example:
>
> test_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>   print(sum_positive_even(test_list)) 6

This is my code:

```
test_list = []
sum = 0
for i in test_list:
    if i%2==0 and i>0:
        return sum+=i
    else:
        return 0
```

Am I doing it completing wrong? it keeps showing error

Comment: _"Your function should return an integer value."_ You don't have a function here. Functions start with `def`.

Comment: your test_list is empty ?

Comment: @vaultah: syntax error on the `return sum+=i` line for starters.

Comment: Yes, you are doing it very wrong.  There is no function in there.  What are these return doing there.  The input list is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l = [1, -3, 4, 2, 0, -5]

>>> filter(lambda x: x > 0 and x%2 == 0, l)
[4, 2]

>>> sum(filter(lambda x: x > 0 and x%2 == 0, l))
6
```

And to define it as a function

```
def addEvenAndPositive(myList):
    return sum(filter(lambda x: x > 0 and x%2 == 0, myList))

>>> addEvenAndPositive([1, -3, 4, 2, 0, -5])
6
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code contains 2 versions: one which would probably be the more experienced programmer's approach and the other one the naive approach, which would be the correction of your attempt.

```
def sum_positive_even(lst):
    return sum(filter(lambda x: x > 0 and x%2 == 0, lst))

def sum_positive_even_v2(lst):
    sum = 0
    for i in lst:
        if i%2==0 and i>0:
            # remember that item by summing it up (don't return it yet)
            sum+=i
        # else: do nothing and check the next item
    # all the list has been checked
    return sum

test_list = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

print(sum_positive_even(test_list))
print(sum_positive_even_v2(test_list))
```

Doc about the functions used in the first version:
[Python built-in sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)
[Python built-in filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

Answer (score 1):

```
# Note:  sum is a built in function

test_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, -2, -8, 8]

def sum_positive_even(lst):
    "Filter using a generator expression and return sum."
    fgen = (n for n in lst if n % 2 == 0 and n > 0)
    return sum(fgen, 0)

if sum_positive_even(test_list) == 14:
    print("OK!")

if sum_positive_even([]) == 0:
    print("Empty list OK!")
```

Answer (score -1):

to return you need to define a method

```
   test_list = [-1, 2, 3, 4]
    sum = 0
    for i in test_list:
        if i%2==0 and i>0:
            sum+=i
    print sum
```

actually if you are writing method

```
 def sum_positive_even(test_list):
      sum = 0
      for i in test_list:
         if i%2==0 and i>=0:
             sum+=i
      return sum 
 sum_positive_even([-1, 2, 3, 4])

#output 6

#sum_positive_even([-1, -2, 3, 5])
#output 0
```

Explantion:

1. to return a method must be defined
2. according to the problem statement,say if first element is -1 the logic directly return 0 without reading other elements of the list
3. so however we are assign sum to 0 if the condition fails to all the elements then sum remains 0.

Comment: Whats wrong with this answer? It works as intendet, doesn't it?

Comment: It appears the answer was wrong at the time you commented, but it has been fixed now. +1